# Visual Studio Code Marketplace in Ubuntu: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, proxy, driver

When I try to search the name of a given extension in Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I get the following error message: **Error: while fetching extensions, XHR failed**.
When I toggle to the developper tools I find this: **ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED**

My proxy settings were specified using the Settings GUI that comes with Ubuntu, in a .conf file inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, in the environment file inside `/etc`, and against vscode using the command `code --proxy-server=http://ip:port`. I also tried to set the proxy settings for chrome using  `google-chrome --proxy-server=http://ip:port` but then I get the following error message:

**libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)**

I also run the following commands for proxy setings:

`gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'`

`gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'ip'`

`gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port prt`

(Obviously, ip and prt denote the real values that I used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the following lines in *home/user/.config/Code/User/settings.json*:

```
    "http.proxy": "http://ip:port",
    "https.proxy": "https://ip:port",
```